# How to stop flickering of install with Epic Game's Launcher on Linux?

Tags: epic-games-launcher

How do you get the Epic Game's Launcher to work correctly on Linux? I followed what was on the Manjaro forums: https://forum.manjaro.org/t/howto-installing-epic-games-and-other-games-via-wine-without-lutris-and-proton/92236

It shows using Wine Tricks: `winetricks -q d3dcompiler_43 d3dcompiler_47 d3dx9 corefonts cjkfonts faudio`

Then there are some common solutions for crashing games:

```
sudo pacman -S --needed \
glew \
lib32-dbus-glib \
lib32-freeglut \
lib32-glew \
lib32-gtk2 \
lib32-imlib2 \
lib32-libappindicator-gtk2 \
lib32-libcaca \
lib32-libcurl-compat \
lib32-libcurl-gnutls \
lib32-libdbusmenu-glib \
lib32-libdbusmenu-gtk2 \
lib32-libgcrypt \
lib32-libid3tag \
lib32-libidn11 \
lib32-libindicator-gtk2 \
lib32-libjpeg6-turbo \
lib32-libmikmod \
lib32-libmodplug \
lib32-libnm \
lib32-libpng12 \
lib32-librtmp0 \
lib32-libtheora \
lib32-libtiff \
lib32-libudev0-shim \
lib32-libvpx \
lib32-libwebp \
lib32-libwrap \
lib32-openssl \
lib32-pipewire \
lib32-sdl \
lib32-sdl2_image \
lib32-sdl2_mixer \
lib32-sdl2_ttf \
lib32-sdl_image \
lib32-sdl_mixer \
lib32-sdl_ttf \
lib32-smpeg \
libcurl-compat \
libcurl-gnutls \
libdbusmenu-gtk2 \
libgcrypt15 \
libidn11 \
libindicator-gtk2 \
libjpeg6-turbo \
libpng \
librtmp0 \
libtiff4 \
libudev0-shim \
libvpx \
libwrap \
openssl \
opusfile \
sdl2_image \
sdl2_mixer \
sdl2_ttf \
sdl_image \
sdl_mixer \
sdl_ttf smpeg
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! Since this is a Q&A site, you should at least edit your post in order to make it look like a question, and then answer it by yourself, as you have already done.

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to add to that if you are using Fedora the command looks like so:

```
sudo dnf install \
wine-core-7.2-1.fc36.x86_64 \
giflib-5.2.1-11.fc36.i686 \
libpng-2:1.6.37-12.fc36.x86_64 \
libpng-2:1.6.37-12.fc36.x86_64 \
gnutls-3.7.3-2.fc36.i686 \
gnutls-3.7.3-2.fc36.x86_64 \
mpg123-1.30.0-1.fc36.x86_64 \
mpg123-libs-1.30.0-1.fc36.i686 \
mpg123-libs-1.30.0-1.fc36.x86_64 \
openal-soft-1.21.1-2.fc36.i686 \
openal-soft-1.21.1-2.fc36.x86_64 \
v4l-utils-1.22.1-2.fc36.x86_64 \
pulseaudio-libs-15.0-5.fc36.i686 \
pulseaudio-libs-15.0-5.fc36.x86_64 \
libgpg-error-1.45-1.fc36.i686 \
libgpg-error-1.45-1.fc36.x86_64 \
alsa-plugins-arcamav-1.2.6-2.fc36.i686 \
alsa-plugins-arcamav-1.2.6-2.fc36.x86_64 \
libjpeg-turbo-2.1.2-2.fc36.i686 \
libjpeg-turbo-2.1.2-2.fc36.x86_64 \
sqlite-3.36.0-5.fc36.i686 \
sqlite-3.36.0-5.fc36.x86_64 \
libXcomposite-0.4.5-7.fc36.i686 \
libXcomposite-0.4.5-7.fc36.x86_64 \
libXinerama-1.1.4-10.fc36.i686 \
libXinerama-1.1.4-10.fc36.x86_64 \
libgcrypt-1.10.1-3.fc36.i686 \
libgcrypt-1.10.1-3.fc36.x86_64 \
ncurses-6.2-9.20210508.fc36.x86_64 \
opencl-utils-1-14.svn16.fc35.i686 \
opencl-utils-1-14.svn16.fc35.x86_64 \
libxslt-1.1.35-2.fc36.i686 \
libxslt-1.1.35-2.fc36.x86_64 \
libva-2.14.0-1.fc36.i686 \
libva-2.14.0-1.fc36.x86_64 \
gtk3-3.24.31-2.fc36.i686 \
gtk3-3.24.31-2.fc36.x86_64 \
gst-devtools-1.19.2-1.fc36.i686 \
gst-devtools-1.19.2-1.fc36.x86_64 \
vulkan-loader-1.3.204.0-1.fc36.i686 \
vulkan-loader-1.3.204.0-1.fc36.x86_64 \
vulkan-headers-1.3.204.0-1.fc36.noarch

dnf clean packages
```

After I installed everything the Epic Games client stopped glitching and started acting normal.

If you have a command for another system please add it!

Here is the list of dependencies that are needed by Epic for their client:
You need to installed Microsoft Visual C++ 2010, 2012,2013 and 2015
These should be installed into the Wine prefix.